# Custom DNS Without Modifying /etc/hosts Mac OS X

Tags: ruby, dns

How would one create a Ruby script that will assign an arbitrary host name to an arbitrary IP? At one point this could be done using [ghost](https://github.com/bjeanes/ghost) however it no longer appears to works under Mac OS X 10.7.3. Can it be done without modifying /etc/hosts on a per user level? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's not ruby, but have you seen [Pow!](http://pow.cx/)? It happens to be implemented in node.js, and sets up a dns server to make your browser think your system is the other host names - dynamically.

HTH,

Kyle

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using [`powder`](https://github.com/Rodreegez/powder) (a wrapper for `Pow`). It is easy to install and easy to use. Everything you'll have to do is simply create a link to your project directory and it will automatically create domain name for you without modifying of your `hosts` file.

Answer (score -1):

[Gas mask](http://www.clockwise.ee/gasmask/) is my tool of choice for mucking around with my hosts config. You can create multiple host files and switch between them as you like.